# Reverse Engineer Serial Communication

Tags: c#, c++, windows, serial-port, reverse-engineering

I have a device which when a certain application is on send data to that application. I need to take a sniff that data and retrieve certain information which is not being shown. The device is custom and for one reason or another has no data sheets. So have to sniff the communication and reconstruct the commands being sent from the application to this device. So I would like to accomplish this in C# or C++. Right now I have tried every sniffing software and yes they sniff it but I want to be able to this live and retrieve the data and present it live.

Thank you

Comment: What kind of device is this? Printer, Card reader, Space Shuttle? Could you please get into detail and post some fragments of code you already developed?

Comment: Just to be clear, you aren't interested in reverse engineering something, but are creating essentially add-on software that will pull information out of an existing stream of data being sent from other software and the port?

Comment: yes you are perfectly right!!

Comment: I think if you tried already different sniffers, there for sure will some that you can use from command line. Why just not call them like separate process and handle output from them in async way?

Comment: ^ that just went over my head :-)

Comment: I think My name says I am a NOOB!!!..lol

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358037/in-c-how-could-i-listen-to-a-com-serial-port-that-is-already-open

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to put your software in between the device and the other software.  Then, pass-through all of the data, capturing out whatever you need.

To do this, you would need to utilize serial port loopback software.  There is a lot of it out there.  See http://www.virtual-serial-port.com/virtual-serial-port-kit.html.  I personally have used a product from GPSGate, but I believe there are [free loopback drivers available](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/).

A more complicated (but more passive!) method is to monitor IOCTLs.  I can't direct you how to do this, as I do not know, but it is something to look into.  The software at http://www.serial-port-monitor.com/ uses this method.

Comment: What I am looking for is somekind of a link to or an actricle explaining how to conduct Snifing using either C++ or C#. So I can Sniff when serial port is active and what is being sent and react accordingly.

Comment: @NoobRS232, see the "How it works" section of this article:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx

Comment: @NoobRS232, if that is over your head, then you should go with the loopback method.  It is much simpler.

Comment: There is no open source solution which I can modify or am I starting from scracth

Comment: @NoobRS232, if you implement that free loopback driver I link to, no big deal.  It's just a matter of reading/writing data to serial ports.  If you want to go at a lower level than that, then I think you'll be starting from scratch.

Comment: Thanks Brad, you have been really Helpfull!!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative piece of software giving you virtual serial ports is com0com (http://com0com.sourceforge.net/). However, it also has a hub functionality where the output of the device can be sent to many applications, which might or might not be useful to you depending on whether you just need to monitor the output from the device or in both directions.

If nothing else it might give you some open source code to base your own sniffer on if you go down the device filter route. But if you go down that route you might need to look at driver signing if you need it to work on 64 bit versions of Windows 7.