# How to write an RS232 sniffer in C#

Tags: c#, sniffer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C# how could I listen to a COM (Serial) Port that is already open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358037/in-c-how-could-i-listen-to-a-com-serial-port-that-is-already-open)

I have a device that communicates with a computer through RS232 (with a USB adapter which doesn't matter). I need to somehow record/log data. I found software to do that but I need something of my own so I can do some other nifty stuff later on as well as during log/capture/sniffing.

Comment: Could be it. In the guy's question his software is communicating with com port where is in mine, another application (not mine) will be communicating with com port and my software (C# written) will be sniffing and analyzing data