# Multiplexing or Listen to Serial Port in use

Tags: c#, serial-port, multiplexing

I access my COM port using the manufacturer hardware DLL in C# .Net 4. Connected to my COM port I have a [Nanotec stepper motor control](http://en.nanotec.com/technology_programming.html) SMCI 33.

The manufacturer provides a flag "SetSendStatusWhenCompleted" to send a Status byte, when the movement of the hardware stepper motor is completed. Unfortunately there is no function to listen to this status byte. I want to add this functionallity.

**Goal:** Send a movement command using hardware driver. Wait for: Listen to the response "status byte" before sending next movement command.

```
using System.IO; using System.IO.Ports;
(... access same com Port via driver of hardware manufacturer. ...)
sp = new SerialPort();
    sp.PortName = "COM4";
    sp.BaudRate = 115200;
    sp.DataBits = 8;
    sp.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
    sp.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
    sp.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.None;
sp.Open();
```

Obviously I get an [UnauthorizedAccessException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.ports.serialport.open.aspx), because my code started the driver and tries to access the same COM Port.
A [similar SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358037/in-c-sharp-how-could-i-listen-to-a-com-serial-port-that-is-already-open) treats the COM access from another program: A Port sniffer (Portmon) is the solution. But my question demands simple code.

I could stop the hardware driver. Currently the issue is time costly re-initialisation.
Is there an other way to listen to the COM Port, than to shut the previous hardware driver down?

Comment: Not sure, but you will probably need some COM redirector or multiplexer. Out of the box, not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the multiplexing keyword. The hub4com from [com0com project](http://com0com.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/com0com/hub4com/ReadMe.txt?revision=RELEASED) provides multiplexing. I'll take a look at it's source.

Comment: That's the app I was thinking of :) Hope it helps.

Comment: Just ditch the "driver" and write all the commands yourself.  Like any stepper controller, it uses a simple ASCII protocol.

Comment: @HansPassant Since I already have the ASCII Protocol, I could write all commands. "A good programmer is a lazy programmer" ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [hub4com](https://sourceforge.net/projects/com0com/) from Nullmodem com0com project provides requested multiplexing. Hub4com implements multiplexing and manages the requests on a com port. This allows both a) driver and b) the OP's code to access the same COM port.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [Monitor tool](http://www.serial-port-monitor.com/), to better understand what your other application really does and what comes on the wire. Additionally you can set up [two virtual com ports](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/) to test reading and writing on one machine (even within the same application), to have a better control about when will which data be send.

Comment: I have the [Nanotec Programming Manual](http://en.nanotec.com/technology_programming.html) which provides the ASCII protocol for serial communication.